# Given an infinite amount of red,yellow and blue balls, all balls of the same color are identical. Choose $10$ balls. How many choices are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Given an infinite amount of red, yellow and blue balls (all balls of the same color are identical), choose $10$ balls. How many choices are there? Note that the order of choice does not matter.

I can divide into cases: there is $1$ choice for a combination containing $10$ red balls; $2$ choices for a combination containing $9$ red balls (since the remaining ball can be blue or green); and $3$ choices for a combination containing $8$ red balls (because the remaining $2$ balls can be either green,green; blue,blue; green,blue) and so on. So I guess that the answer is $1+2+3+...+11=66$, but I don't know how to justify my logic for all cases. For example, how to justify, using standard methods of combinatorics, that for a combination containing $6$ red balls, there are $5$ possible choices, without counting all the possibilities?

Comment: See [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Your answer is correct. In terms of stars and bars the it is $\binom{10+3-1}{10}=66$.